# Renaming directory bash script - target ... No such file or directory

Tags: bash, scripting, file-management

I've been testing this on a simple directory structure.
I'm trying to change any directory and/or sub directory with the name "Season" to "Sn".
I got to a point where the script would change what I wanted...except for the top directory, as seen in the list below - "Season 1" "Season 2" "Season 3".

Directory structure:

```
.
├── AnotherShow
│   ├── Sn1
│   ├── Sn2
│   ├── Sn3
│   └── Sn4
├── Movie1
│   ├── Sn1
│   └── Sn2
├── Movie2
│   ├── Sn1
│   ├── Sn2
│   ├── Sn3
│   └── Sn4
├── Movie3
│   ├── Sn1
│   └── Sn3
├── Movie4
│   ├── Sn2
│   └── Sn3
├── Season 1
├── Season 2
├── Season 3
├── Show
│   ├── Sn1
│   ├── Sn2
│   ├── Sn3
│   ├── Sn4
│   └── Sn5
└── TV
    ├── Sn1
    ├── Sn2
    ├── Sn3
    └── Sn4
```

My script is:

```
array="$(find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname 'Season*' -print)"; # A more refined way to search for Seasons in    a directory.
for dir in "${array[@]}"; do # Put this list into an array.  Surround the array with quotes to keep all space   s (if any) together.
   new="$(echo "$dir" | sed -e 's/Season 0/Sn/' -e 's/Season /Sn/')"; # Only change Season 0 to SN.  Leave othe   rs alone.
   sudo mv -v "$dir" "$new" && echo Changed "$dir" to "$new"; 
done
```

Comment: Seems to work here (without `sudo` though). What is the output of `find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname 'Season*' -print`? Replace `sudo` with `echo` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not creating an array, you are creating a string. You can test this quite easily by attempting to print the first element of your array:

```
$ array="$(find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname 'Season*' -print)"; 
$ echo $array
./Season 3 ./Season 1 ./Season 2
```

Looks good right? But if that were an array, you would be able to print each element separately. Unfortunately, the above is a simple string<sup>1</sup> and not an array:

```
$ echo ${array[0]}
./Season 3 ./Season 1 ./Season 2
$ echo ${array[1]}
```

The array actually consists of a single string which is why the second element of the "array" (`${array[1]}`) is empty. In any case, you don't need an array for this, just read through the output of `find` (you also don't need the `-print`, that's what it does by default). A working version of your script could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -iname 'Season*' | sort -r |
while IFS= read -r dir
do 
    mv "$dir" ${dir/Season /Sn} && echo Changed "$dir" to "$dir/Season /Sn}"; 
done
```

There are a couple of tricks used there. First, the `while` loop to go through the results of `find`. This is the same basic principle as the `for` loop that you used but combined with `read` can read from standard input.

The `IFS=` is needed to avoid splitting on whitespace (without it, the directory `Season 1` would be split into `Season` and `1`).

The `-r` of read tells it to not allow backslashes to escape characters (things like `\t` and `\n` are treated literally) which makes sure this can deal with even the strangest names.

The `sort -r` is needed so that if you have a directory matching the pattern inside another matching directory, the child is listed before the parent. For example:

```
./Season 12/Season 13
./Season 12
```

This ensures that you run `mv "Season 12" "Sn12"` *after* running `mv  "Season 12"/"Season 13" "Season 12"/"Sn13"`. If you don't do that, the second command will fail since `Season 12` no longer exists.

Finally, I removed the `sudo`. You should instead run the script as `sudo script.sh`. It is never a good idea to have random `sudo` calls in your scripts.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'm not sure about the details but apparently, bash treats string variables as arrays of one element.</sub>

Comment: If there are not files in 1st level folders with names started with `Season ` and it's names(folders) havn't spaces you can exclude `find` - just use `for`: `for dir in ./*/Season\ * ; do ... ; done`

Comment: @costas yes but unfortunately, there are 1st level directories starting with Season and there are also spaces in the names as clearly indicated in the OP.

Comment: As I understand from "directory structure" there are not subdirectories *Season* under 1st level directories with same name and OP have not intend to rename 1st level directories so the above globbing should satisfy.

Comment: Additionally `for dir in */Season\ */ ; do ...` works on my system even with spaces in 1st level dirname and gets just directories *Season* not files.

Comment: @Costas please read the question. The whole point of the OP is that their original approach did not rename `./Season 1`, `./Season 2` and `./Season 3`. Anyway, yes, while globbing is often better, it is not a good idea here since it would also affect files and not only directories (unless you use the syntax you show in your second comment), something that `find` avoids.

Comment: @Costas yes, spaces are completely irrelevant here, you're globbing. But try this: `mkdir "Season 1"; touch "Season 1/Season 2"; mkdir -p foo/Season12; for dir in */Season\ */ ; do mv "$dir" foo; done`. That will miss both `./Season 1` _and_ it will miss any directory without a space in its name. Anyway, why don't you just post an answer using globbing instead of posting comments? Comments [should not be used](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for long discussions.

Comment: @terdon Thank you so much for explaining everything in detail, this is very helpful.  I used your script above and it didn't work....just hangs.  It prints out: "./Season 1", "./Season 2", "Season 3", but then hangs.  I've tried to change a few things in the script to get it to work, but it's not working for me.

Comment: @Happyworker make sure you run it in the directory where the target dirs are. If it hangs, it is probably being run in a much larger directory with many files and folders. Is the directory very large?

Comment: @terdon Nope, it's my Testing directory.  Just directories as you see above with no files in the directory.  I am running it in the Testing directory (top level)

Comment: @Happyworker yes, that's because I'm an idiot and forgot to pipe the output of `sort` to the `while` loop. Try again with the updated version.

Comment: @terdon Thank you, I think it's going to work...but I'm getting "mv: cannot move `./Season 3' to `./Sn3': Permission denied".  So I tried sudo season_ch.sh and I'm getting "sudo: season_ch.sh: command not found".  Sorry total newbie here, I have all my scripts in my /home/me/bin/

Comment: @Happyworker Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18396/discussion-between-terdon-and-happyworker).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know yet what the problem is but I have a few remarks about your script.

Try not to call binaries (with a single piece of data) in a loop. That kills performance.

You should call the whole script with sudo but not sudo within the script.

You don't need `sed` for changing the file names. `bash` can do that itself:

```
if [[ $dir =~ "Season 0" ]]; then
  new="${dir/Season 0/Sn}"
else
  new="${dir/Season /Sn}"
fi
```

Or without the `if`:

```
new="${dir/Season /Sn}"
new="${new/Sn0/Sn}"
```

You don't need the array:

```
find ... | while read dirpath; do
```

This has the "advantage" that spaces in the directory name don't break the array definition. I have no idea why your `array="$(find ... -print)"` works. It should not (because the shell should not make a difference in word splitting between space and newline).

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just short variant of above

```
for dir in ./*/Season\ */ 
do
  mv "$dir" "${dir/eason /n}" && echo "$dir changed to ${dir/eason /n}"
done
```

Works with subdirs *Season*. If you will want to rename files (not dirs only) just remove `/` at the end of pattern so it looks like `./*/Season\ *`

If you need `sudo` I'd offer you to do it in one-line-command (not a script)

```
for dir in ./*/Season\ */ ; do sudo mv -v "$dir" "${dir/eason /n}" ; done
```